# Telling PixiJS that the WebGL state has been modified externally

Tags: pixi.js

I am trying to integrate PixiJS with an existing custom WebGL engine. The existing custom engine is the host and handles control to PixiJS every frame. The existing custom engine configures the WebGL state to an "almost" default state and then calls into PixiJS; after PixiJS is done, the existing custom engine does a full reset of the WebGL state.

In code:

```js
onFrame() {
  resetWebGLStateToDefault(gl);
  gl.bindFramebuffer(...)
  gl.viewport(...)
  thenWeUsePixiJSToDoSomeAdvancedStuff();
  resetWebGLStateToDefault(gl);
}
```

**My question**
*In `thenWeUsePixiJSToDoSomeAdvancedStuff()`, how can I tell PixiJS that the state is not what it used to be the previous time that it ran? Pretty much everything has been reset; PixiJS should assume that everything is default and I would also like to tell PixiJS what the current viewport and framebuffer are.*

I tried `Renderer.reset`, `StateSystem.reset`, `StateSystem.forceState` but I guess that's not enough; PixiJS keeps assuming that some textures that it has set previously are still bound (they are not, the existing custom engine unbinds everything) and I get lots of `[.WebGL-0x7fd105545e00]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit ?`. Pretty much for all texture units, 1-15, except the first one.

#### Edit

It's probably worth mentioning that I am calling into the renderer directly; I think I need to because the existing custom engine owns the render loop. I am basically trying something like this, but I am getting the WebGL texture errors after the first frame.

```
          renderer.reset();
          renderer.render(sprite);
          renderer.reset();
```

#### Edit

I tried the same thing with an `autoStart: false` application, and I get the same error.

```
          pixiApp.renderer.reset();
          pixiApp.render();
          pixiApp.renderer.reset();
```

Comment: For this kind of stuff probably you will need to dig in the code of PIXI.js . You can also try asking at their forum : https://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/15-pixijs/ - i see that some people already tried working with custom WebGL code and PIXI - see: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/43738-any-way-to-integrate-pure-webgl-code-in-graphic-hierarchy-of-pixi/?tab=comments#comment-244889  or https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/14522-combining-my-own-webgl-code-with-pixi/

Comment: Thank you @domis86, really good suggestion. I am getting some good help there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that I was calling into PixiJS with a currently bound FBO; I fixed all my problems by creating a separate `PIXI.RenderTexture`, rendering there, and then compositing on top of my WebGL engine using a fullscreen quad.

```
        // Create a render texture
        const renderTexture = PIXI.RenderTexture.create(640, 360);

        // Render with PixiJS
        renderer.reset();
        renderer.render(this.stage, renderTexture);
        renderer.reset();

        // Retrieve the raw WebGL texture
        const texture = renderTexture.baseTexture._glTextures[renderer.texture.CONTEXT_UID].texture;

        // Now composite on top of the other engine
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, theFramebufferWhereINeededPixiJSToRenderInTheFirstPlace);

        gl.useProgram(quadProgram);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.uniform1i(u_Texture, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quadBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.BYTE, false, 2, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.useProgram(null);
```

You may need to `resize()` the renderer and/or the render texture, depending on your actual setup.